# How to know if Virtual Environment is working in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

(Disclaimer: New to coding and VS Code)

I’ve read through VS Code’s documentation on creating a virtual environment and I’ve used the VENV command to do so, but how do I know if my current Python files are working using that Virtual Environment.

In the folder I’m saving my .py files in, I see the .venv folder which was created.  Is that it or is there more to it?

I’ve used VS Code’s terminal commands and followed the documentation instructions, but there is no documentation to tell me exactly what I’m supposed to see when it works, so I don’t know if I’m done.

I see the .venv folder which was created in the “Python Projects” folder I created before I began my code learning joirney.  Is that it?

Comment: You can check this by looking at the interpreter being selected in the bottom right corner of the VSCode window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You want to check if you are in the venv or not:

Type `which python` into VS Code's integrated terminal.
If you are using the venv, it will show the path to the python executable inside the venv: (For me, the .venv folder is located in /Users/lion/example_folder, but for you it would be located differently)
[image: Example of which python in the venv]

If the path does not include the .venv folder inside your Python Projects folder, then you are not inside the venv.
(Example: the path shown by the command is /usr/bin/python, but the .venv is at /user/Python Projects)

> You are not inside the venv and you want to activate it

Inside VS Code's terminal, type `source .venv/bin/activate` (Or, the absolute path: `source ~/example_folder/.venv/bin/activate`)

Comment: And yes, the .venv folder you are seeing is the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is it. Once an environment has been created, you may wish to activate it, e.g. by sourcing an activate script in its bin directory.

```
.venv\Scripts\activate
```